# Click on overlay div to activate shadowbox with effect

Tags: jquery, css, shadowbox

i am trying to create a gallery where i click the on  overlay div and thus shadowbox modal opens with corresponding image.
here is my markup

```
 <li class="grow pic">
 <a class="shadowboxLink" href="img/car_details/1large.jpg" rel="shadowbox">
 <div class="overlayForCarDetails"></div>
 <img class="mediumImg" src="img/car_details/1medium.jpg" alt=""></a>
 </li>
```

Now when i click the a link it works fine.
I wanted to add an effect to image on link overlay
so i added jquery like this

```
        $('.shadowboxLink').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).children('.overlayForCarDetails').css('opacity', '0.7');
            $(this).children('.overlayForCarDetails').next().find('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');
        });
```

but somehow the class is not applied.

the class is

```
.zoomed {
-moz-transform: scale(1.10);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.10);
-o-transform: scale(1.10);
transform: scale(1.10);
-ms-transform: scale(1.10);
}
```

**Please tell me where am i doing it wrong.**
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('.shadowboxLink').mouseenter(function () {

            $(this).children('.overlayForCarDetails').css('opacity', '0.7');
            $(this).children('.overlayForCarDetails').next('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You unnecessarily added `.children('.overlayForCarDetails').next().find('.mediumImg')` when you can just use `.find('.mediumImg')`
Change to:

```
$('.shadowboxLink').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).children('.overlayForCarDetails').css('opacity', '0.7');
    $(this).find('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain why was I down voted? Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yap9c/1/) with my code. It works fine.